# which way is best and worst to find and display customer lived in newyork? stateful or stateless or singleton?

Tags: ejb, session-bean

I am trying to get the **number of customer who lived in newyork** and display on my page. But some doubt in my mind, which way is best to worst, Like **stateless**, **stateful** and **singleton** ejb? Any idea, which way i have to implement my application.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it would be Stateless.
As long as there is no state accross several invocations there is no need for a Stateful Bean.
A singleton could be a bottleneck, as i would not use a method like getCustomersinNewYork() but getCustomers(City city), and a Singleton is only one instance which should be used to synchronize. But it is possible to have the method concurrent and store a Map with results for each City - but consider you need to handle the concurrency.

From my point of view I would keep the application stateless and let the StatelessBean calcuate the number of customers per city for each request.
If there is a need to enhance the performance because the requests are repeated I would use a cache like Infinispan to store that - i.e. with expiration to recalculate the number from time to time or let it drop it not used for longer.

Make sense?